# ROS Answers SE migration: Costmap layers

Tags: ros, navigation, layered-costmap, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

is there a way to insert and remove a costmap2d layer through code (not manually) during an operation?

I want to insert a virtual confinement *(i thought its best to do it with map Layers)* for my turtlebot and then remove it after a certain condition has been met.

UPDATE: does anyone know of the "Parameter" that can enable/disable a Costmap layer during run time?

Thank you guys :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207172/costmap-layers/) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, costmap layers are not changed during runtime. However, you can have a parameter that enables/disables the layer.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-04-16**:
@David Lu thank you very much. can you tell me the name of this parameter and that where i can set it (config file or within the code)? appreciate it.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-04-17**:
Most layers have a dynamically reconfigurable parameter called "enabled" https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/cfg/ObstaclePlugin.cfg

**Comment by [brettpac](https://answers.ros.org/users/24752/brettpac/) on 2015-10-22**:
@David Lu, Could you please elaborate a little more regarding loading a costmap layer during runtime. Aside from setting the enable parameter via dynamic reconfigure, would it also be necessary to "restart" costmap2DROS so that the new costmap layers are loaded into layeredcostmap?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-10-22**:
http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps